# Резервное копирование и миграция данных

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Существуют ли какие-либо инструменты для backup/restore данных с сервера на Google App Engine? Нашел только для Python, а мне нужно для Java. Важно, чтобы была возможность не только сохранять/восстанавливать данные, но и делать рефакторинг базы данных. Как вариант можно написать собственную backup/restore утилиту, но тогда возникнут проблемы с ограничением выполнения запроса на сервере в 30 секунд (иначе возникает `HardDeadlineExceededError`). А при восстановлении запросы могут превышать этот лимит (это контролировать как-то непросто).

Answer (score 1):

Под Java такого [нет](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Bulk_downloading)

Comment: Хотелось бы понять, как это реализовать самому. Без бэкапа и миграции система работать не сможет.